# Increasing function $ f : \mathbb R ^ + \to \mathbb R $ with $ x f ( x ) + 2 > 0 $ and $ f ( x ) f \left( f ( x ) + \frac 4 x \right) = 1 $

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $ f : \mathbb R ^ + \to \mathbb R $ be an increasing function, such that $ x f ( x ) + 2 > 0 $ and $ f ( x ) f \left( \frac { x f ( x ) + 4 } x \right) = 1 $, then find the value of $ \lfloor f ' ( 1 ) \rfloor $ (where $ \lfloor \cdot \rfloor $ represents greatest integer function).

My approach is as follow $ f ( x ) f ( y ) = 1 $ as $ y = \frac { x f ( x ) + 4 } x $, I am trying to use the function given as $ x f ( x ) + 2 > 0 $ in $ y $ but I'm not able to proceed.

Comment: Note that $f(x)=1$ satisfies all of these requirements.

Comment: By trying some rational functions I found in addition of $f(x)=\pm 1$ the solution $f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2x}$, but I don't know how to get there directly. Yet this shows that there are non-trivial solutions.

Comment: @PeterForeman $f(x)=1$ is not increasing.

Comment: @Adam It's not strictly increasing but it's increasing because clearly $x\gt y\implies f(x)\ge f(y)$ as $1\ge1$.

Comment: @PeterForeman I would call that non-decreasing, but I see it's a matter of nomenclature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\frac{xf(x)+4}{x}=f(x)+\frac{4}{x}$. We have 
$$ f(x)f(g(x)) =1$$
Since $xf(x)+2>0$, we also have $g(x)>\frac{2}{x}>0$, which means that we also have
$$ f(g(x))f(g(g(x))) =1$$
which means that
$$ f(x) = f(g(g(x)))$$
since $f$ is an increasing function, it means that
$$ x=g(g(x))=f(g(x))+\frac{4}{g(x)}= \frac{1}{f(x)}+\frac{4}{f(x)+\frac{4}{x}}$$
Solving for $f(x)$, we can find
$$ f(x) = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{17}}{2x} $$
Since we know that $f$ is increasing, we must conclude that the minus sign is the correct one
$$ f(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2x} $$
Form this, we find
$$ f'(1) = \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2} $$
$$ \lfloor f'(1)\rfloor = 1$$